# Laravel Ckfinder How to config error 403 Forbidden

Tags: laravel, ckfinder

[image]

What happened?
Although the request was valid, the page/resource you are trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

Why it happened?
The web server thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the web browser was correct, but access to the resource identified by the URL is forbidden for some reason.
This is highly likely due to the reason that your recent action or browser behavior has been flagged as suspicious, either you have failed all authentication tests, including CAPTCHA, or performed an action on a protected application deemed illegal or malicious by the Web Application Firewall (WAF).
Access to the requested page/resource is therefore blocked. If the source IP is on the blacklist, you will keep seeing this page until being removed from the blacklist.

What can I do？
Clear your browser’s cache and try again. If you believe this to be erroneous, please contact the site owner citing the Event ID indicated above and provide a description of what you were doing before you were denied access.

Comment: You need to provide some details as to your code and what it does.